# Where can I "practice" PL/SQL

Tags: database, plsql

I will be given a job offer by an IT company, and was asked to "look at" PL/SQL since I didn't have much experience with databases. I have an extensive background in C++ among other programming languages, so I don't think this will pose too much of a challenge. However, I don't have access to any Oracle database at home, so I was wondering if there is a "toy" database and terminal online where I can practice.

Comment: I'm flagging this question for closure, as it is asking for recommendations of off site resources. This question has produced some useful resources for people with this issue, so deletion may not be appropriate, however it should be closed so that future users do not think that questions like this are on topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Register yourself an account at [APEX ONLINE](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html) you have all of the tools for free available online, or simple download [Oracle Database 10g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest a higher priority would be to learn the Relational model of data, then SQL.

If you don't start with a solid understanding of the RM, you're more likely to tend to use procedural solutions where a set-based approach is better.

Answer (score 7):

Go and get the Express version of the database server [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

As for learning PL/SQL start
[here](http://www.stevenfeuerstein.com/learn/learn-plsql)

Answer (score 2):

You just download sql developer tool by using this link..do practice well.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

Answer (score 0):

There is another site where you can practice PL/SQL online:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/oracle_terminal_online.php

Oracle have some VM images with Oracle Linux ready-to-run:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/downloads/vm-for-hol-1896500.html (64bits VM)

Comment: another one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/template-1482544.html

Answer (score 0):

To learn PL/SQL language you just need a text editor like atom or sublime text. You can also install MySQL.